# How do I fix this alignment issue in jQuery & CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

The implementation is here: http://jsfiddle.net/JWaCY/1/

Look at the 'Forgot Pass?' link. When you press 'Register', it disappears and when you click 'Login' again, it comes back inline - which is where I want it to be. Right beside the 'Register' button.

However, what's happening now is that because the button 'Send Reset Instructions' is right beside the 'Register' button with css display & visibility values of none and hidden respectively, on first load it is showing the space where this button would be.

How do I allow it to be hidden fully, without the space being taken up and the 'Forgot Pass?' positioned right beside the 'Register' button on page load?

I would rather a CSS solution.

I know I can do this with jQuery by simply executing a `$('#pass-reset').slideUp();` somewhere within my JS on the page load, but that shows the 'Forgot Pass?' literally moving from below the buttons to the right side - which is untidy. I would much rather a more elegant solution that just shows the Forgot Pass in the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the following CSS and it seems to work now:

```
div#sign_in input#pass-reset {
    display: none;
}
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/JWaCY/2/

Hope this helps.

Bob

Answer (score 1):

the forgot password link was being positioned by an invisible element, which was subsequently toggled to display none;

It has display none in it's CSS but it was over ridden by a display block;

I make the display:none !important and made the link display block with some margin on top:

http://jsfiddle.net/NfCyJ/